# Using jquery in ajax window

Tags: ajax, image, jquery-ui, jquery

I am using Jquery UI ajax tabs to display the content on my site. The tabs are working great. On each on of my Ajax tabs I have an image rotator that is not working so great.

The image rotator requires jquery to work properly. All of the jquery image rotator plugin files seem to be working fine except for this code...

```
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


            var banner1 = $('#banner-rotator1').royalSlider({
                imageAlignCenter:true,
                imageScaleMode: "fill",

                hideArrowOnLastSlide:true,
                slideSpacing:20,

                autoScaleSlider: true,
                autoScaleSliderWidth: 1150,
                autoScaleSliderHeight: 400
            }).data("royalSlider");             


            var banner2 = $('#banner-rotator2').royalSlider({
                imageAlignCenter:true,
                imageScaleMode: "fill",

                hideArrowOnLastSlide:true,
                slideSpacing:20,

                autoScaleSlider: true,
                autoScaleSliderWidth: 1150,
                autoScaleSliderHeight: 400
            }).data("royalSlider");  

            var banner3 = $('#banner-rotator3').royalSlider({
                imageAlignCenter:true,
                imageScaleMode: "fill",

                hideArrowOnLastSlide:true,
                slideSpacing:20,

                autoScaleSlider: true,
                autoScaleSliderWidth: 1150,
                autoScaleSliderHeight: 400
            }).data("royalSlider");

            var banner4 = $('#banner-rotator4').royalSlider({
                imageAlignCenter:true,
                imageScaleMode: "fill",

                hideArrowOnLastSlide:true,
                slideSpacing:20,

                autoScaleSlider: true,
                autoScaleSliderWidth: 1150,
                autoScaleSliderHeight: 400
            }).data("royalSlider");
        });
```

I know the code works because if I cut and paste it into the ajax pages it works fine, but I can't seem to get the image rotator to work when the code is placed in the "master page". Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is a link to my page http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Ajax-Test/Ajax-stripped.html

Answer (score 1):

It's because this code is run when the DOM is ready, that is, the master page DOM is ready. You later load your ajax content and the javascript code has already run prior to the ajax content loading. What you can do is place that code in a function. Then in your ajax loaded content run that function on `document.ready`

E.g

In your masterpage

```
function code_to_run(){ 
    // your code here 
}
```

In your ajax loaded content

```
$(function(){ 
    code_to_run() // call the function in your masterpage 
});
```

Comment: I would like to keep all jquery out of my ajax pages. It looks like a lot of mobile browsers have a hard time loading the jquery from off of the ajax pages. Do you know a way to to do this? perhaps a different call or something?

Comment: Um, sure. You could also do this in the callback, after the ajax page has been loaded.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. Sorry I am pretty new at this. Would you mind sending an example?

Answer (score 0):

The interaction of Master Pages and Content Pages is complex and may be understood better by looking at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36107/Master-Page-and-Content-Page-Interaction.
Therein you find a paragraph describing how to reference Content Pages from the Master Page. 
I hope this helps